# LinkedList vs LinkedBlockingQueue performance

Tags: java, collections

I've the next code:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue< String > messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue< >( INITIALCAPACITY );
//current thread calls
private synchronized String waitMessages() throws InterruptedException {
    while( messages.isEmpty() ) {
        wait();
    }
    return messages.remove( );
}

//another thread calls
public synchronized void received( String message ) {
    messages.add( message );
    notify();
}
```

So I run this code the same input data for LinkedBlockingQueue and LinkedList and I found that first implementation executes faster than LinkedList. It's a strange behaviour for me, because I though that LinkedBlockingQueue requires extra time for inner blocking mechanism.

1) Could you explain such results?

2) Is there any Queue(or List) implementations that could be faster for such task than LinkedBlockingQueue (ArrayList is definitely slower)?

---

Comment: 1) Most likely your benchmark is broken. 2) LinkedBlockingQueue without the synchronzied / wait loop.

Comment: 1) Hadly it'could be broken, it just send the same amount of the same messages and measures the time of processing. The results is 10 and 16 seconds accordingly 2) sure, but may be another implementation?

Comment: 1) I would ignore the warm up period of at least 2 seconds. 2) How much effort are you willing to go to? This is a lot faster https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/

Comment: BTW ArrayBlockingQueue is faster provided you never fill the array.

Comment: just test ArrayBlockingQueue wasted 12 seconds

Comment: Why would you remove wait loop? It should looks like "while ((str = messages.take()) ==null){}return str;"

Comment: @pswrdf with `LinkedBlockingQueue` you can simply use [`return messages.take();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()). There is no need for a while loop, the `wait()` or the synchonization. Similarly for `received`: `messages.offer(message)` - no synchonization or `notify()` necessary.

Comment: If you are going to use a BlockingQueue, I would use the blocking operations. IMHO The whole point of using a BlockingQueue is so you don't have to busy wait for either an offer or take.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for explanation.

Answer (score -1):

So the first question may be answered so: LinkedBlockingQueue allocate memory on init stage (constructor). But LinkedList do it every insert operation on runtime stage.

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue does this but LinkedBlockingQueue doesn't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you are rigth, so assumption is wrong.